# Redirect ?lang=en string to subfolder /en

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'd like to do a lot of redirects like this pattern:

`domain.com/xxx/?lang=en` to `domain.com/en/xxx/`

For example:

`domain.com/about/?lang=en` to `domain.com/en/about/`

This redirects all links `*/?lang=en` to just one target.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en
RewriteRule ^ en/about/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ $2/?lan=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Change `302` to `301` once you make sure code is working fine.

Comment: Fails: `https://example.com/fr`Not Found, however `https://example.com/fr/index.php` works.