# example.com/en to behave as example.com?lang=en to example.com/en - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added translations to my website and it uses the GET variable `lang` from the URL such as `example.com?lang=en` to show the right language.

I would like to make it look like `example.com/en`.

Also `example.com/somePage.php?lang=en` should likewise look like `example.com/en/somePage.php`

The language parameter would always be 2 letters right after the domain, so always `example.com/xx.../.../...whatever-url`

If nothing is given (For example `example.com` or `example.com/whatever-url`) then `en` is default

So I believe we need to take into account that if there's a folder or file called `en` or whatever, it should give priority to that folder / file. Not sure how to handle all the required filtering however.

I tried that, which fails (says page not found when I go to `/en`)
BUT `example.com/en/index.php` works.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ $2/?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/24943513/1741542

Comment: I did learn a bit with that, but I get page not found when going to example.com/en

Comment: Have you changed the URLs in your application to look like `example.com/en` etc.?

Comment: I went to `/en` on my site and page not found, I edited my post to reflect what I've tried so far

Comment: `example.com/fr/index.php` works though

Comment: how to get rid of index.php in example.com/en/index.php so example.com/en works?